# Chat is still showing Facebook profile photo url and additionally [D] "tag" is before URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, gravatar, facebook

```
<img src="[D]http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/186005_1427291500_3162901_n.jpg">
```

resulting in

http://phpcode.eu/images/1314223247.png

in chat room.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A last-minute change to an API meant that this was overlooked. A fix is deploying currently, and should take effect the *next time your profile is refreshed* (about every hour if you are using chat).